# Advice for deeply nested filtering with nested object for RXJS in angular?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, rxjs, filtering

Quick Question:

Pardon me, I'm fairly new to Typescipt & RxJS. I have the following JSON:

```
[
{
    "ID": "",
    "UEN": "",
    "Name": "",
    "Address": "",
    "Telephone": "",
    "Fax": "",
    "Email": "",
    "Website": "",
    "Postal": "",
    "Status": ,
    "TimeCreated": ,
    "TimeUpdated": ,
    "Workheads": [{
            "ID": "",
            "Name": "",
            "Code": ""
        },
        {
            "ID": "",
            "Name": "",
            "Code": ""
        }
    ]
},
...
]
```

This json is feed into my angular app via Observable from HTTP get().

**How do I filter** the workhead.Code section such that **I could get those relevant Json** objects within the array **by matching the inner workhead.Code** to a specific string that has been provided by the user **(e.g. workhead.Code == 'CS2230')?**

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are not clear exactly what you want returned. I assume you want the full objects returned, and not only the inner `"Workheads"`. You can use a `filter()` to get what you want:

```js
const data = [{
  "ID": "",
  "UEN": "",
  "Name": "",
  "Address": "",
  "Telephone": "",
  "Fax": "",
  "Email": "",
  "Website": "",
  "Postal": "",
  "Status": "",
  "TimeCreated": "",
  "TimeUpdated": "",
  "Workheads": [{
    "ID": "",
    "Name": "",
    "Code": "abc"
  }, {
    "ID": "",
    "Name": "",
    "Code": "def"
  }]
}];

// Returns an array of the objects which contain matching code.
const getRelatedByCode = (arr, userProvidedCode) => {
  return arr.filter((i) => {
    return (i.Workheads || [])
      .some(wh => wh.Code === userProvidedCode);
  });
}

console.log(getRelatedByCode(data, 'abc')); // Returns array with the object
console.log(getRelatedByCode(data, 'zzz')); // Returns empty array
```

Comment: @Spectric, thanks alot for the help. Really appreciate it. :)

Comment: @Spectric, what happens if filter is string[] and not string?

Comment: @Kim You should be thanking **dacodr** instead. He was the one who posted the answer, I simply edited it :)